# pandas: add new column computed from row and partner row

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that are paired such that rows come in pairs, their `id` named `a` and `b`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['1a', 'A', 5], ['1b', 'B', 10], ['2a', 'C', 20],['2b', 'D', 4]], columns=['id', 'name', 'count'])
>>> df
   id name  count
0  1a    A      5
1  1b    B     10
2  2a    C     20
3  2b    D      4
```

`1a` and `1b` are a pair, and `2a` and `2b` are another pair. I want to create a new column `rel_count` in which the value is the row's own `count` divided by its partner's `count`:

```
   id name  count  rel_count
0  1a    A      5        0.5
1  1b    B     10        2.0
2  2a    C     20        5.0
3  2b    D      4        0.2
```

What is the best way to do this in pandas?

Comment: `df['count'] / df.groupby(df.id.str[0])['count'].transform(lambda x: x[::-1])`?

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape to 2d array, flip and flattenting by ravel:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1a', 'A', 5], ['1b', 'B', 10], 
                   ['2a', 'C', 20],['2b', 'D', 4], 
                   ['3a', 'C', 10],['3b', 'D', 5]], 
                  columns=['id', 'name', 'count'])
print (df)
   id name  count
0  1a    A      5
1  1b    B     10
2  2a    C     20
3  2b    D      4
4  3a    C     10
5  3b    D      5

#if not sorting by pairs
#df = df.sort_values('id')

a = df['count'].values.reshape(-1, 2)[:, ::-1].ravel()
print (a)
[10  5  4 20  5 10]
```

If is possible distinguish groups some way - first letter like @Zero commented or extract first `int` value:

```
g = df['id'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
a = df.groupby(g)['count'].transform(lambda x: x[::-1])
print (a)
0    10
1     5
2     4
3    20
4     5
5    10
Name: count, dtype: int64

print (g)
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
Name: id, dtype: object


df['rel_count'] = df['count'] / a
print (df)
   id name  count  rel_count
0  1a    A      5        0.5
1  1b    B     10        2.0
2  2a    C     20        5.0
3  2b    D      4        0.2
4  3a    C     10        2.0
5  3b    D      5        0.5
```

Comment: what if they're not sorted by pairs? :)

Comment: You can sort it by `df = df.sort_values('id')`

Answer (score 0):

Probably, not best approach but you could do it in this way:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index % 2 == 0:
        df.ix[index, 'rel_count'] = float(df.ix[index, 'count']) / df.ix[index+1, 'count'] 
    else:
        df.ix[index, 'rel_count'] = float(df.ix[index, 'count']) / df.ix[index-1, 'count']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
df["g_id"] = df.id.str[0]

df_groupbed = df.set_index(["name", 'id', 'g_id']).groupby("g_id")["count"]
df_groupbed.nlargest(2)/df_groupbed.nsmallest(2).values

g_id  name  id  g_id
1     B     1b  1       2.0
      A     1a  1       0.5
2     C     2a  2       5.0
      D     2b  2       0.2
Name: count, dtype: float64
```

First, we add a `g_id` by using the `str` method. Then, we group by `g_id`

I used `nlargest` and `nsmallest` to reverse the order within each group.

Answer (score 0):

By even and odd, I mean rows in dataframe. `.values` is required to avoid problem with mismatched indexes in series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['1a', 'A', 5], ['1b', 'B', 10], ['2a', 'C', 20],['2b', 'D', 4]], columns=['id', 'name', 'count'])

df['rel_count'] = np.nan
even = df.loc[::2, 'count']
odd = df.loc[1::2, 'count']
df.loc[::2, 'rel_count'] = even / odd.values
df.loc[1::2, 'rel_count'] = odd / even.values
```